# Unable to display the stored image in imageview?

Tags: android, bitmap, nullpointerexception, imageview, bitmapfactory

```
    Intent i = getIntent();
    mPathString = i.getStringExtra("imagepathstring");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mPathString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    try {
        Bitmap temp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mPathString);
        capturedImageView.setImageBitmap(temp);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
```

Here the code runs perfectly and even the toast displays the correct path of the image that I am storing on external storage. But still the image does not appear on the imageview. And if i remove the try and catch block surrounding bitmap object then my app fails with nullpointer exception. Can any one help to figure out what mistake I have done..?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that you have initialized you `capturedImageView`. I think that your `capturedImageView` is `null`.

Comment: +1 yeah... you're almost certainly right. If the path was incorrect the Bitmap would be null, but passing a null bitmap to setImageBitmap is totaly legal. So, the problem is almost certainly that capturedImageView was never initialized to point at a valid View.

Answer (score 2):

please set your capturedImageView with layout imageview.
i think then it works fine.

```
ImageView capturedImageView;
capturedImageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.capturedImageView);
```

Comment: That worked....a silly mistake on my side....apologies...Thank you very much as would have never traced out that silly mistake by myself. Thank you again.

Comment: yes i know sometimes its happen. in try catch block it handles it and your app works fine but when you remove it your app crash due to exception rise

Answer (score 0):

```
 mPathString = i.getExtra.getString("imagepathstring");
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the path you are using, and how are you generating it?  It may not be exactly right.

Ah, and Roman Black may be right.

Comment: Everything else is right with generation of path and image storing. Thank you.